# How to keep loaded data in RAM when using torch.utils.data.DataLoder?

Tags: python, pytorch

I'm using `torch.utils.data.Dataloader` to load my data. I stored my data in a global python `dict` variable when `dataloader` loaded it through a `__getitem__` function in a `torch.utils.data.Dataset` object. But it released all the memory after every training epoch was done. Then it loaded all data from the hard disk again.

```py
# in data.py file
from torch.utils.data import Dataset, DataLoader

PRELOAD_DATA = dict()

class Data(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, some_path):
        self.file_list = some_path  # a list contains all the file path

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.file_list)

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        if index in PRELOAD_DATA:
            this_blob = PRELOAD_DATA[index]
        else:
            this_blob = load_data_from_disk(self.file_list[index])
            PRELOAD_DATA[index] = this_blob  # I try to store data in this line
        return this_blob

def multithread_dataloader(some_path):
    this_data = Data(some_path)
    this_dataloader = DataLoader(this_data, batch_size=1, shuffle=True, num_workers=8, drop_last=False)
    return this_dataloader
```

```py
# in main.py file
from data import multithread_dataloader

file_path_list = ...  # a list contains all the file path
train_data = multithread_dataloader(file_path_list)
for epoch in range(100):
    for blob in train_data:
        # training
```

Comment: Have you tried making PRELOAD_DATA a member of your Dataset class? It should work then.

Comment: @tilman151 I tried to place a `self.preload_data = dict()` in `__init__` function of `Data` class and used it to save the data. The memory still released after every epoch.

Comment: This is weird. You're talking about CPU memory not GPU, correct? What exactly is your error message?

Comment: @tilman151 Yes, it is CPU memory. There was no error message. When one training epoch was completed, I found that the memory usage in the Windows Task Manager dropped from above 90% to 13%. Then with the next training epoch, the memory usage gradually increased to above 90% and the hard disk usage was nearly 100%.

Comment: Did you try to check if the data is really reloaded (via debugger or print). The memory that is cleared should be mostly the gradient data which accumulates over the epoch.

Comment: You can return a copy of a tensor from your dataset.

Comment: @Mirodil Thanks for your idea. I loaded data in another class and send this class to the `Data` class. Now my data stays in RAM.